# Can you use future tense and switch to present in the same sentence?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, future

As in:

> Occasionally, he will spontaneously generate the sentences on his own
>   and sometimes uses, "May I have."

Comment: "he will generate..." is not future.  It refers to an action that is occasionally repeated.

Comment: It is the future tense of the verb *generate*. It is being used here with a habitual present meaning. They do that all the time in Scots Gaelic, but it as rare variant to the present in English. That is significant in this question because it is about two tense forms being used interchangeably where they have essentially the same meaning.

Comment: I will post an answer if I think of one.    Joe will not post an answer; his computer is broken.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In spoken English, it may be acceptable for this sentence, but in written English.

> “. . . and sometimes (he will) **use** . . .”

Yes, we can! You can learn additionally about [if-clause conditions](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/intermediate-grammar/conditionals-1) to see how it works.

If you like my answer, you will mark an answer as correct (the green check image) on this answer. :)

Comment: Should it be changed to 'use' instead of 'uses' in the sentence?

Comment: Yes, it **must** be changed **into** “use” without an “s”